# In pycharm can I run every file for django?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm new to Django. My localhost site is running fine. Since I am using pycharm it is easy to run any file. I decided to run each file in my django project, and came across several errors, such as this one in my views.py:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Even though the site is running, what seems like properly, I'm seeing this message. What is causing this, and is it typical?

Comment: Your website is running through something other than pycharm still.  You need to do what the error states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run each file present in your django project individual.

No matter those are file with `.py` extension. They depend on the django framework to get the project running.

The reason you might be seeing that error is because you might be using the attributes present in the `settings.py` file which in turn requires django to set the application running like starting the `WSGI` server, getting all the dependencies and the `installed apps` ready before you actually use anything.

Understand that Django is  a Framework and it relies on many underlying components to actually work. Even thought you can technically run any file in any manner, you cannot start the application itself.

There are other ways to do it if you like to test the application like using `django shell` by `python manage.py shell` to check and test the application, which would be a better way of doing individual testing rather than running each file standalone.

Answer (score 0):

**You can run** any individual **python file** in a Django Project with Django, but keep in mind that the settings for Django must be supplied. This is not a good practise to run individual file with Django but for debugging purposes you may use it (*for example. to test a parser that you wrote with database access*),

You have to configure the Django settings before you can do anything with Django on a single file.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

def do_something_with_a_model():
    # does something with a model
    print "I am done!!"
```

Note that relative imports may break when running on single files.

(*for example. imports like `from .another_module import AnotherClass` may break when working with single file.*)